# Defining a macro to add the prefix 0x to a hex string literal

Tags: c++, hex, preprocessor

I am trying to get a macro to work in my c program to add `0x` to a HEX literal as follows:

```
#define BUILD ABCD0000

#define CONCAT(m, n) m ## n
#define HEX(x) CONCAT(0x, x)

const uint32_t Id = HEX (BUILD);
```

I get this compiler error: invalid suffix "x" on integer constant.
Can anyone help?

Comment: remove spaces between m and n

Comment: [Cant reproduce](https://godbolt.org/z/tRLbEZ).

Comment: Why bother?  Seems like typing `0x` is a lot simpler than using your complex macros.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews you're right, but maybe there are other contexts where the `BUILD` macro should be converted to a string without `0x` using yet another macro.

Answer (score 3):

This is not the answer that you expect, but I am sorry, I have to:
**DON'T DO THIS!!**

Why not ?

- It is misleading: The name and the syntax `HEX(x)` leads to think would convert x to hex, whereas it requires the argument to already be in hex.
- It behaves badly: `HEX(ABC00+10)`  would take the first part has hex but the second part still in decimal. To let macros behave well with expressions, the trick is to enclose each use of a parameter between parenthesis, but this is not possible with concatenation.
- It goes against [POLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment) for you peer developers
- Better get accustomed to `0x` : it appears in a lot of code around there, in compiler messages, in debuggers,  etc... So train your eyes instead of trying to escape.

This being said, after having tested on a couple of compiler versions on godbolt, I could not reproduce your error.  So if you want to go on:

- Maybe your old compiler is disturbed by spacing (remove all spaces in macro definitions and macro uses). Or, it shouldn't, but who knows, the two `x` in the macro to expand?
- Or maybe your compiler expects each token used in a macro to be valid (e.g. strings must be closed, literals valid, etc...). I remember having such limitations but on very old C compilers in the 80's, perhaps 90s*

Answer (score 0):

This is resolved now. I got it working on another compiler and then realized that it was actually generating a blank for the BUILD value ie just #define BUILD